# Access SQL Append rows from one table to another using a WHERE clause (with multiple values)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables with identical structures (i.e. columns) one with data for the last day of the month going back a few years(2012-2013 and another with daily data for one specific year (2014. I wanted to move the last day of the month data for every month in the second table into the first table using SQL but the code doesn't seem to work! Here is the statement:

```
sSql = "INSERT INTO [Month_End_AR_Detail] SELECT * FROM [AR_Detail] WHERE [Date] IN (1/31/2014,2/28/2014,3/31/2014,4/30/2014)"
```

Am I missing a syntax? The columns are identical but should I reference them individually instead of the asterick? or maybe my WHERE with multiple conditions is improper?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query instead. You need to include the date within pair of #

```
sSql = "INSERT INTO [Month_End_AR_Detail] SELECT * FROM [AR_Detail] WHERE [Date] IN 
(#1/31/2014#,#2/28/2014#,#3/31/2014#,#4/30/2014#)"
```

If the number of columns and order of the columns are same then * should work. Otherwise you need to explicitly specify the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Dates need to be surrounded by `##`

e.g.

```
#1/1/2001# // is correct
1/1/2001   // is not
```